# Implementing Github library

Tags: python-3.x, github

I want to be able to use [this code base](https://github.com/ChadFulton/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/sarimax.py) for my own statistical modeling:

I have **no** idea how to implement a file/feature set I find on Github.  I would appreciate help on this.  I apologize if this is general or overly obvious, but it is not obvious to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by implement a file/feature set, but if you mean you want to download the source you should look into guides on how git works.

I suggest you take a look here:
https://guides.github.com/
or here
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository

Essentially git is a system to keep track of code, changes to code, and issues/bugs. A repository, like the one you listed, is essentially just a folder thats contents get tracked for changes.  Typically the model works something like this:

1. You want to start a new project, so you create a git repository folder on your computer.
2. You generate code, and "commit" these changes to the change log in the local repository.
3. Once you have done a bunch of work, you "Push" those commits to github, where other people can "Pull" them down.

In this case someone has already created a repo (repository), and you seem to want a copy of it, so you can "clone" it.  There are various ways you can do this, I suggest you look into the guides above for a method that will work for you.